# camel-cxf problem

Tags: apache-camel

I have cxf webservice and I want to call that by camel.

could anybody help me.

my source is:

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <camel:package>com.aliti.integeration</camel:package>

    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:helloService?defaultOperationName=sayHello"/>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:helloService?defaultOperationName=sayHi"/>

        <log message=">>>> ${body}"/>

    </route>

</camel:camelContext>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will expose a service on localhost:8080/test and send requests through your route

```
from(cxf://http://localhost:8080/test?serviceClass=com.aliti.integeration.HelloService)
.choice()
    .when(header(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME).isEqualTo("sayHello"))
        setBody(constant("hello")
    .when(header(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME).isEqualTo("sayHi"))
        setBody(constant("hi");

...
public interface HelloService {
    String sayHello();
    String sayHi();
}
```

For more information, take a look at the [camel-cxf](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html) page, the [cxf unit tests](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-cxf/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/CxfConsumerTest.java) and this [blog post](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/12/basic-rest-service-in-apache-cxf-vs.html) for an CXFRS example...

Comment: I try it, but I don't got anything.

Comment: Do you know how to write this in XML config?

Answer (score 0):

Just try camel in code; there you can choose your method. But in DSL mode I do'nt have any idea.

like boday say:

```
.choice()
    .when(header(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME).isEqualTo("sayHello"))
        setBody(constant("hello")
    .when(header(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME).isEqualTo("sayHi"))
        setBody(constant("hi");
```